# What does the [[ -z "$PORT" ]] && export PORT=8080 bash command do?

Tags: bash

I am following a tutorial and they use the command
`[[ -z "$PORT" ]] && export PORT=8080` and I don't fully understand what it's doing. My knowledge of bash commands is very basic and so I am not even sure what to google to figure this out.

The little knowledge I have suggests to me that this somehow checks if the env variable `PORT` is set and if not set it to `8080`. However, I don't actually understand what is going on, except for the last part, `export PORT=8080`.

Could anyone explain what the different operations are doing here?

Comment: see `help [[` and `help test` and `help export` in your shell.

Comment: This is a clumsy way to write `: ${PORT:=8080}`; the `export` is probably unnecessary (or else it should be outside the conditional).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what is going on -

- `[[ -z "$PORT" ]]` is checking whether the length of the string in variable `"$PORT"` is zero or Not.
- the second part of `&&` is only evaluated if the first part is true.

So short answer is this -

if the length of the string `"$PORT"` is zero then it will export a variable named `PORT` which will have the value of `8080` otherwise it will not export the variable and will moved on to the next statement in bash script.

Answer (score 2):

Using `&&` there is taking advantage of it being a ["short-circuiting" operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). It tests the first command, and only executes the second command if it fails.

So this is a short-hand way of writing

```
if [[ -z "$PORT" ]]
then
    export PORT=8080
fi
```

Which means if `$PORT` is unset or empty, it's set to `8080` and exported.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's clarify that the first command is an expression:

[image]

Try this:

```
echo $foo
```

it will yield empty string. Now, if you execute

```
[[ -z "$PORT" ]] && export PORT=8080
```

and then run

```
echo $foo
```

then the result is 8080.

Explanation:

- `-z string` is true if `string` is empty and false otherwise
- the right side of `&&` is evaluated if and only if the left-hand side is true, otherwise the logical expression is evaluated as false
- the right-hand-side does an `export`

In short: `$PORT` is defaulted to 8080.